# Tablix cells set to Vertical Writing Mode appearing empty

Tags: reporting-services

I have upgraded a 2014 report to 2016 that has some column headers displayed as vertical text. When I view the report in Visual Studio 2015 the labels show correctly:

[image]

When I deploy the report to my 2016 report server the vertical column header text is not rendered - the cells appear empty:

[image]

The rest of the report renders correctly.

What do I need to do to get the vertical column header text to display correctly?

Interestingly if I download the rendered report from the report server to Excel the headings are there.

Comment: Is the screenshot of the expected behaviour or the problem behaviour and in either case, what does the other behaviour look like?

Comment: Hopefully the newly added screen shot shows the issue

Comment: So the rotated text is not displaying at all - that's the issue?

Comment: Yes that's the issue. Displays if you preview in visual studio 2015

Comment: What property is set for `Localization->WritingMode` for the cells which should contain rotated text? I just created a new report and published it to a 2016 SSRS report server and both the `Vertical` and `Rotate270` settings worked fine for me.

Comment: The Writing Mode is set as Vertical

Comment: I thought this was fixed. It was a bug in 2012 with a non-ie browser and the solution was to convert text to images and rotate the image. I do remember hearing that the bug was fixed in 2014, however, I will try to confirm.

Comment: @Ewan you say that the report previews fine in Visual Studio, but your screenshot appears to be from Design View, not Preview - I presume the cells appear exactly the same (empty) when the report is actually previewed in Visual Studio? Perhaps you could update your screenshot to show the actual preview, just for clarity.

Comment: @RossBush I just tried my test report in Chrome and it worked fine there too.

Comment: So it looks like the upgrade process does not work properly from your comments. Its a complex report that I would rather not recreate is there a way round?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is for each textbox with Writing Mode = Vertical, is to set Can grow to True. The text then displays